# Could the Orion project pusher plate model be used for asteroid deflection?

Tags: asteroid, near-earth-asteroid, asteroid-redirect-mission

Could the [Orion project pusher plate model](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/15051/3201) be used for asteroid deflection?

Basically, the plates (or hemispherical shells) would be deployed in the vicinity  of the asteroid , and the following nuclear blasts would push the asteroid-plates system on a different path. Depending on the composition of the asteroid , a direct nuclear blast in its vicinity (with no pusher plates) would be less efficient (and then there is the fragmentation problem).

How efficient would this deflection system be in relation to large asteroids (km range), and in relation to other deflection options?

Comment: Note that you assume you can "push" on the mass of the asteroid in the first place; this might be true for a sufficiently large asteroid, but most asteroids seem to be mostly loose assemblages of dirt and such, rather than solid objects - push, and you disintegrate the asteroid, instead of changing the momentum of the bulk of its mass. This isn't a problem for deflection through a solar mirror or gravitational tractor, but a big problem for both "nuclear missile strike" and your Orion approach.

Comment: @Luaan Wouldn't  10 asteroids of, say, 20,000 t each be preferred over 1 asteroid weighing 200,000 tons, even if they all reach Earth (which some may not)?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider There's great analysis on http://stardestroyer.net/Empire/Essays/Planet-Killers.html#Asteroid (and more on other pages on the site). In short, there's a few things it makes better, and a few things it makes much worse.

Comment: @Luaan I read the Asteroid section, but saw nothing about One Large vs. Lots of Medium asteroid hits.

Comment: @RonJohn Look at the kinds of damage that are described there and their relative importance; now think about which of those are going to be diminished by a multiple-asteroid strike, and which are going to be even more destructive. I know there was an even better article that specifically dealt with many small vs. one large, but I can't find it.

Comment: @Luaan if you break an asteroid into 10 pieces, and one misses, then you've reduced the damage by 10%.  That's not any use if the rock would cause 10^7 MT damage, but for smaller asteroids, it would be better than nothing.  And they could be more easily deflected by other methods.

Comment: @RonJohn Is it really easier to deflect ten small asteroids? I don't think any of the methods discussed would work better for many small asteroids than for a single solid asteroid. In fact, that's the main reason why we don't think they would work at all, ever since we realized that most asteroids are *not* solid. As for the damage, compare what a single nuclear bomb does compared to an equivalent energy amount of conventional explosives does more dispersed. A single large (~100 m) asteroid can level a city. A hundred small asteroids (~10 m) can level a hundred cities.

Comment: @Luaan I see your point.  According to https://www.space.com/19741-asteroid-2012-da14-earth-impact-effects.html an airbust 10m asteroid releases about the same energy as a small nuke.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The challenge here is getting the pusher plate into position. The potential impactor is not generally traveling on an orbit that can be reached with low DV. So the only way with current(ish) technology to get 100-1000 tons of pusher plate alongside and stationary to an asteroid is if it uses an Orion drive. And if you have a fully working Orion then you can dock with the asteroid and do whatever you want with it.

Getting an intercept with an asteroid is a lot easier (lower DV) but that will have your pusher plate approaching the asteroid at speeds where pusher plate turns to vapour anyway, with or without one more nuclear detonation (it probably got there with an Orion drive). And still tend to disrupt the target.

The Nuclear deflection model is generally built on assumption that if you can only get 100kg onto a intercept course it might as well be nuclear, if you can launch 100-1000 ton payloads without using nuclear devices then just using them alone is simpler and probably more predictable in terms of final outcome.

Comment: You don't need to deploy a large , compact Orion pusher plate in space (for large asteroids). You could consider a fleet of smaller  Orion pusher plates, each one powered by Davy Crockett type nuclear warheads.  The large pusher plate would be composed of  many smaller elements.

Comment: @CristianDumitrescu And the asteroid's mass would leak through the spaces between the pusher plates, and on the edges of the whole assemblage. To really get most of the mass of the asteroid, you'd need a huge pusher plate that forms a bowl with a volume about equal to the volume of the asteroid. If you can build an asteroid-sized construction in the first place, deflecting asteroids is easy :D

Comment: @ChristianDumitrescu for moving loosely assembled threats you probably want https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_tractor, which because you want it to be heavy might indeed be an Orion thrust plate.

Answer (score 5):

This depends on the size and composition of the asteroid. Many asteroids are loose rubble piles, held together by weak gravity only. So you can't really park a small ship on the surface and start thrusting: you'd end up pushing the ship through the asteroid.

When the ship diameter is about the same as the asteroid, it could work.

Comment: Do loose ruble pile asteroids need deflection?

Comment: @Oxy Yup. Rubble asteroids are still more than enough for large scale destruction of the Earth. The three largest known asteroids are fully differentiated (like planets) - and those start at 500km diameter. The fourth is already *very* oblate, though it seems solid enough. The 50km 253 Mathilde is already definitely a rubble pile - I probably don't have to tell you what the impact of such an asteroid would do to our climate :) Of course, it's possible to have a smaller asteroid that's fully solid, but for "danger that needs deflection", the upper limit is the important thing :)

Comment: Same as my comment above, you could consider a fleet of smaller Orion pusher plates, each one powered by Davy Crockett type nuclear warheads.

Comment: So the pusher plate diameter (constructed of smaller elements) would be the same as the asteroid.

Comment: Project Orion used the smallest bombs they could think of (which turned out to be only slightly larger than the Davy Crockett devices) to arrive at a ship weight of 800 tons at a diameter of 25 m. That's tiny compared to the kind of asteroid you'd want to deflect, and simultaneously more than we can currently launch in 1 year.

Comment: @Hobbes  For the original Orion project the pusher plate was designed to withstand multiple detonations.  For the purpose of asteroid deflection the requirements would change,  and with new materials available today I am sure the necessary weight would be smaller.

Comment: I think you underestimate the mass of even a small asteroid.

Comment: That could be true, I am not familiar with the numerical values of the many parameters/variables involved in this model, but I think it's worth a detailed study by experts.

Comment: Asteroid Bennu is 250 m across, and weighs 14 million tons.

Comment: So you need to calculate the necessary momentum transfer induced by let's say 10  small Orion ships. A tiny deflection angle early in its trajectory could mean the difference between hitting or not hitting Earth later. This is a feasibility study, and a complex model, I don't think back of envelope calculations can answer it in a satisfactory manner. Compared to any other deflection methods though,  to me it looks the most promising.  Only breaking it apart with powerful nuclear blasts in its vicinity might be better.

Comment: @CristianDumitrescu Again, the impulse is not the problem. You wouldn't even need an Orion-style propulsion for that. The problem is applying that impulse to most of the mass of the asteroid. Keep in mind that when comparing diameter to area, you need to square - it's not a linear relation. So if we assumed the 250m asteroid Hobbes mentioned is a perfectly flat cylinder, it would have an area of 100 000 m^2. Your "small" Orion ship (which is already well beyond our capabilities) would have an area of merely 1 000 m^2. You'll need 100, not 10, minimum.

Comment: @CristianDumitrescu But wait, that still doesn't help anything. You're pushing on a rubble pile. Have you tried using a plate to push on gravel or sand? It's going to spill over. Ultimately, you would flatten it completely, with most of the mass dripping to the side, and continuing on much the same trajectory. Some of the mass would be dispersed enough to miss, but a nuclear strike would probably work better (but still not well enough). That's why the current best approach we have is the gravitational tractor - it produces a tiny acceleration, but over the whole mass of the asteroid.

Comment: Thank you for the correction @Luaan  that's correct.  I randomly picked the number  10 because 100 or more seemed less realistic,  having in mind that not even one Orion ship is functional today. Each type of asteroid   , whether C-type, S-type or M-type would require different strategies. If gravitational tractor method works (given enough time), the Orion pusher plate model would work for short notice threats, when the threat is detected late (at least for M-type). But you are correct,  probably the best method is to blow them up with a proper distribution of blasts in their vicinity.

Comment: But then again, like GWrangler noticed above, what kind of fuel  are you going to use, in order to chase an asteroid far from Earth, detonate a distribution of nuclear charges around it, see the outcome and have sufficient time for corrective actions (or repeated blasts)?  Do you think gravity assist and conventional fuels will allow you to do all that? The Orion project might not be feasible for interstellar travel, but for asteroid deflection would be optimal, whether you consider the pusher plate model or chasing it for further actions.

Comment: I am not an expert,  but my humble opinion is that compared to the Orion project applied for asteroid deflection,  absolutely all the other methods are a joke.

Comment: Correction,  maybe not all. Laser arrays in orbit,  powered by the Sun, an adaptation for asteroid deflection of Peter Glaser's project from the 1960s (meant for free energy supply initially). But this is even more futuristic and costly,  even than the Orion project.  Bottom line, nothing serious is being done in this direction of planetary defense (except for NASA with a tiny  budget). We are going to party till doomsday, talking about inefficient deflection methods that would take decades to deploy and years of operation, in order to be efficient.